# Hypothesis testing

Tags: machine-learning

I am a novice at machine learning. I am trying to understanding how and where the hypothesis testing is done in the model building process. Is it to measure the quality of the population data during the feature engineering process ? If yes, how is it applied?

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. Hypothesis testing is not a necessary step for building a model, it's something which can be used for some specific purpose in some specific context. "measuring the quality of the data" is also something which would be specific to a particular task, there's no general concept for this.

Comment: Hypothesis testing is usually applied to make a choice. Choice can be between different sets of features, between two or more candidate models, or between declaring presence/absence of an effect (e.g. A is associated with B or not). I don't think there will be a concise answer to this question. You can use hypothesis in many places.